# Python - Increment Characters in a String by 1

Tags: python, chr, ord

I've searched on how to do this in python and I can't find an answer. If you have a string:

```
>>> value = 'abc'
```

How would you increment all characters in a string by 1? So the input that I'm looking for is:

```
>>> value = 'bcd'
```

I know I can do it with one character using ord and chr:

```
>>> value = 'a'
>>> print (chr(ord(value)+1)) 
>>> b
```

But `ord()` and `chr()` can only take one character. If I used the same statement above with a string of more than one character. I would get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I can't believe nobody came up with a solution for this using recursion

Comment: @Alexander Cherednichenko How would you do this problem by using recursion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a generator expression with `''.join()` as follows:

```
In [153]: value = 'abc'

In [154]: value_altered = ''.join(chr(ord(letter)+1) for letter in value)

In [155]: value_altered
Out[155]: 'bcd'
```

The generator iterates over each `letter` in the string `value` and increments it by one using the `chr(ord(letter)+1)` methodology suggested in your question. It then uses `''.join()` to convert the letters in the generator back into a string.

Comment: A generator expression might be more natural here, since you don't actually need the list. Just get rid of the square brackets inside the `join` call: `"".join(chr(ord(letter)+1) for letter in value)`

Comment: thanks @Blckknght, I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 8):

As gtllambert beat me to my original answer, I am posting an alternative solution. You can also use `map` and a lambda expression to achieve the same. The lambda expression uses `chr` and `ord` to increment each character by one and `chr` is used to convert it back to a character.

```
value = 'abc'
''.join(map(lambda x:chr(ord(x)+1),value))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
value = 'abc'
newVar=(chr(ord(value[0])+1))
newVar1=(chr(ord(value[1])+1))
newVar2=(chr(ord(value[2])+1))
value=newVar+newVar1+newVar2
print(value)
```

Here is what I came up with can't believe it actually worked thanks for the challenge using python 3

Comment: You should use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple four line piece of code:

```
finalMessage=""
for x in range (0,len(value)):
    finalMessage+=(chr(ord(value[x])+1))
print(finalMessage)
```

It goes through each letter in the string and adds one to it, but this doesn't work with "z", so you could do:

```
value="abc testing testing, or sdrshmf"
finalMessage=""
for x in range(0,len(value)):
    if ord(value[x]) in range(97,123):
        finalMessage+=(chr(((ord(value[x])-96)%26)+97))
    elif ord(value[x]) in range(65,91):
        finalMessage+=(chr(((ord(value[x])-64)%26)+65))
    else:
        finalMessage+=value[x]
print(finalMessage)
```